# Is a Noetherian scheme of dimension $0$ affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've shown the proposition in the title, but I have no confident.
This is the proof:

First by Grothendieck Vanishing Theorem, for all $i \ge 1$ and every sheaf of abelian group $ \mathscr{F},$ $H^i(X, \mathscr{F}) = 0,$ and so in particular, this is so for quasi-coherent sheaves.
Therefor by Serre's affine criterion, $X$ is affine since $\operatorname{dim}X = 0.$

This is so short and easy, and I think important, but I couldn't find this statement anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much easier proof, not invoking results in cohomology.

Note a noetherian scheme of dimension zero necessarily is a finite colletion of discrete points. Since the disjoint union of affine schemes is again affine, you are left to show that a scheme, whose topological space is a point, is affine. This is trivial.